# Partial view inside modal dialog is not working (jQuery)

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, jquery-ui, jqgrid

I have a column in JQGRID with two controls (textbox & button) on click of button I should show a dialog box with partial view content. Here is the code I'm using:

```
function RenderModalPopup(rowid, event) {
    debugger;

    $("#dvedit_showDialog").dialog({
        modal: true,
        autoOpen: false,
        width: 500,
        height: 800
    });


    $.ajax({
        url: '/Edit/GetPopupPartial',
        type: 'POST',
        success: function () {
            debugger;
            //$('#dvedit_showDialog').html(Data);
            $('#dvedit_showDialog').load("@Url.Action('GetPopupPartial','Edit')").dialog('open');

        }
    });
}
```

My intention is I need to create a modal dialog which can be reused across the project. The partial view may vary. Please help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

first load the partial view then create modal dialog.

```
$.ajax({
            url: '/Edit/GetPopupPartial',
            type: 'POST',
            success: function (data) {
                debugger;
                $('#dvedit_showDialog')
                    .html(data)
                    .dialog({
                        modal: true,
                        autoOpen: true,
                        width: 500,
                        height: 800
                    });

           }
        });
```

Comment: i change solution. you no need `load()` function anymore